# how to migrate to utf8 for a multi-customer shared codeBase in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, file-conversion

in our company we use a proprietary CMS,
this CMS is in use for almoust a thousand websites and is aged of approximatively 15 years.
(it has evolved but is very features rich)

until now whe have always used iso-8859-1 as charset, but whe have the nescessity to use utf-8 for one project.

**there are my questions :**

1. do you think that this way to do is good (maintaining one SVN version, automatic conversion to the utf8 search/replace the problematic php functions and do some magic there).
2. Have you done this kind of evolution before, what is hasardous regarding to you?

---

**TLDR infos :**

- the core of our CMS is centralised (SVN) and deployed (rsynch) on a specific path on each of our servers, this path is in the include path of each websites.
- The databases are different for each projects (but same structure for the core tables).
- each website use a document_root holding website's specifics files (media, js, specific PHP code)

in this configuration, we cannot migrate every website on a single time (ie : because there is local code).
So I want to make two version of our core : one in iso-8859-1 and the other in utf8.
From now I think that I'm going to develop a script on our deployement system, this script, will create a copy utf8 encoded of our core before the rsynch-ing.

My concern is for example about all the "mb_*" stuff in PHP that won't be called, so i'll have to search/replace every php native fucntion to replace it by a custome one that will use the "mb_*" version if nescessary (furthermore, the overloding of those functions must be in the php.ini file, it cannot be defined in the .htaccess of a particulare website ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php)))

PS : sorry for my poor english, it's not my native language :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how I handled it :

- each server is either iso-8859-1 or utf-8, and have dedicated conf (ie : mbstring.func_overload)
- before each deployement a script create a copy of the iso version and convert it to utf8
- each server get either utf-8 or iso-8859-1 source code

for each individual CMS, a convertion tool exist, it convert filesystem, database charset/collation, configuration (ie : connect to mysql with utf8), ....

for non compatible functions such as utf8_encode, I search/replaced it with a function who is in charge to not call the function if the server is utf8